# Is it possible to install two different versions of Visual Studio in the macOS

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

Is it possible? or there is a compatibility issues between the two versions visual 2019 and 2022?
Can I still install a newer version without affecting the older version of visual studio?
Could you please help on this.

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/installing-multiple-versions-visual-studio-side-side/ You might find this helpful :)

Comment: At least on Windows, that works without any issue. I haven't tested, but I assume that's the case for the MacOs versions as well. The only thing that doesn't work is having multiple versions of the same VS version installed (e.g. 17.0.1 and 17.1.0)

Comment: All the recent versions should be compatible. However, depending on extensions installed, there might be issues encountered. Visual Studio code won't cause you any issues as it's a completely seperate thing.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, yes you can. As long as they identify as different applications.